# The timing of opacity transitions after API call in React App

Tags: css, reactjs

Here's an interesting problem. My React App has an issue.
I have a button which invokes getRandomQuote(). gets a line of text from an api and delivers it to the front end. I'd like the text opacity to be 0, then turn to 1 after the text has appeared. instead, the text appears after being called, then turns to 0 opacity, then transitions to opacity 1.

```
getRandomQuote() {

    document.getElementById('quoteText').style.opacity = 0;

     axios.get('http://localhost:3100/quote').then(response => {

        console.log('1111111', response);

        this.setState( {quote: response.data[0].quote_text, quoteAuthor: response.data[0].author} );
        document.get
    document.getElementById('quoteText').style.opacity = 1;

      })
  }
```

index.css

```
.quoteText {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

}

.quoteAuthor {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;

}
```

appContent.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="app" style={ styles.appContent }>          
          <header>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </header>
          {/* <ParticleContainer style ={styles.particleBackground}></ParticleContainer> */}
          <div style={ styles.aboveParticles }>
              <Title words="QUOTE MACHINE" style={styles.title}/>
              <div  style={ styles.quoteBox }>
                <h2 id="quoteText" className="quoteText"  style={styles.quoteText  }>{ this.state.quote }</h2>
                <h2 id="quoteAuthor" className="quoteAuthor" style={  styles.quoteAuthor }>{ this.state.quoteAuthor }</h2>
              </div>
              <button className ="button"  onClick={ ()=>{this.getRandomQuote(); this.changeBackgroundColor(); } } style={ styles.button }>Retrieve a Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not clear. The text will appear with opacity 0 to 1 after first click, and disappear with opacity 1 to 0 then appear with opacity 0 to 1 after second click.

If you mean you want the text disappear immediately after second click, you can change the first line of the getRandomQuote to

`this.setState({quote: ''});`